# how to speed up the cache of the browser using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

I'm writing a blog using wordpress with Altervista like a domain.
I have a problem to increase the rank of my web site becouse the  browser use to much cache memory.
So my question is how to resolve it?

I had installed some plugins but they change a part of my css and html code.

I made the speed test with google insights and the result was 70 for the mobile and 81 for the PC.